# Unending Series of Rooms

Tags: history-of, trope

My instinct is that there is a fantasy trope of the hero/protagonist exploring a (seemingly) unending series of rooms.  I feel like I have encountered this trope in multiple books, but the only one I can think of off the top of my head is GoT (Daenerys in the House of the Undying).

Is this a general trope, and does it have a name?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Asking for an open-ended list of examples is off-topic for our site, so I've edited your question to ask about the general trope instead. I hope that doesn't violate your intent and will give you what you were looking for.

Comment: Are you including situations [where there is a _finite_ number of rooms but you can take an _infinite_ straight walk through them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22%E2%80%94And_He_Built_a_Crooked_House%E2%80%94%22)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TV Tropes calls this [Oh Look, More Rooms!](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OhLookMoreRooms)

> A subtrope of [Bigger on the Inside](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BiggerOnTheInside). A place looks fairly normal from the outside, and possibly even when you get in, it's of a reasonable size. But there's this door in the back. Open it, and... there's a whole new section of the place, easily as big or bigger than everything you've seen so far! And look - there's a door in the back of that too, which leads to yet another new section - or worse, *five* doors...
>
> Basically, it's when [Bigger on the Inside](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BiggerOnTheInside) keeps happening to the point of an [Overly Long Gag](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OverlyLongGag). Related to [Big Labyrinthine Building](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigLabyrinthineBuilding). Can be especially nightmarish in the [Mobile Maze](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MobileMaze), where you can also know that the rooms *weren't* there before.

The examples listed on this page under Literature include the House of the Undying from *A Song of Ice and Fire*, and also the Temple of a Thousand Rooms from *The Neverending Story*, which was the example that sprung to my mind immediately from your explanation.

Comment: And of course the grandaddy of them all,  _Gormenghast_.

Comment: My personal favorite variant of this is [_The Library Of Babel_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel).  Because _that's_ a place I want to visit.  (Getting an actual _library card_ to check out books would be even better!)

Comment: A more recent version, not listed in that wiki page, is Susanna Clarke's wonderful *Piranesi*.

Comment: @davidbak Using the [website](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel_(website)) is cheaper and just as useless as a library card would be.

Comment: @davidbak Have you read The Invisible Library series?

Comment: @curiousdannii - Never heard of it!  But I'll start it now, thanks!

Comment: @RossPresser - Wonderful website, thanks for the pointer! The "image search" is also fantastic and the algorithm behind both rather astonishing (as I had no idea there was a class of "reversible" pseudo-random number generators!) (Though I guess I should have ... it's kind of like arithmetic coding in a way ...)